# Keycloak Docker-compose doesn't uses postgres image

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I'm working with Windows 10 system. I run *docker-compose up -d* to start postgresql and keycloak images. I use docker volume to save database data. My docker-compose file content:

```
version: '2.2'

volumes:
  files_volume:
    driver: local
  
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: test_postgres
    volumes:
      - files_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_DB=test"
      - "POSTGRES_USER=super-admin"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=super-password"
    mem_limit: 256m
    restart: unless-stopped
    
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:10.0.2
    hostname: keycloak
    container_name: keycloak
    volumes:
      - files_volume:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/log
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: 'postgres'
      DB_DATABASE: 'test'
      DB_USER: 'super-admin'
      DB_SCHEMA: 'keycloak'
      DB_PASSWORD: 'super-password'
      KEYCLOAK_USER: 'admin'
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: 'admin'
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: 'true'
      JDBC_PARAMS: 'useSSL=false'
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - "18080:8080"
    mem_limit: 1024m
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_started
```

Docker starts normally, but I can't see keycloak schema on this postgres database. When I connect to keycloak and create realm, clients and so on and *docker-compose down* after restarting I see that there is no data left for keycloak. No realm, no clients, nothing. I believe that keycloak doesn't see postgres and use H2 database.

I use volume because I can't use direct folder. Maybe I'm doing something wrong with volumes? I am quite new to docker.

Comment: Can update the DB_VENDOR environment variable with lowercase “postgres” and try?

Comment: You missed to mention DB_PORT and you are not running in default port.

Comment: @Achu inside the docker network the Postgres database is running on the default port. The non-default host port binding is irrelevant.

Comment: @masseyb - I believe that it doesn't matter if postgres would be upper case or lower case. Achu - I can use whatever port I want, which is in ports range. 5432 is default for postgres, but it doesn't mean that in is a must. And masseyb is right too.

Comment: @DainiusJava have you tested?

Comment: @masseyb - yes. Thanks for the answer, but it didn't changed anything. But I have found what I did wrong. Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem by stopping docker compose and removing keycloak and postgres containers. Then removed volume. Then started docker-compose and everything worked just fine. I believe, that I was starting docker old containers with docker compose, they were cached. So, every time when changing docker compose file, the container, which properties were changed, must be removed.